# Why do I get a “cannot assign” error when do assertion?

Tags: go

req is a interface{} and PostAccountRequest,CreateAccountRequest is struct, when I do this, I get `cannot assign *account.PostAccountRequest to v (type *account.CreateAccountRequest) in multiple assignment`

```
v, ok := req.(*account.CreateAccountRequest)                                                         
if ok {
    if v, ok = req.(*account.PostAccountRequest); ok {
        panic(ok)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The snippet of code defines one variable `v` with type `*account.CreateAccountRequest`.   The second type assertion attempts to assign a `*account.PostAccountRequest` to the variable `v`.  This is an error.

The code will compile if you create a second variable `v`:

```
v, ok := req.(*account.CreateAccountRequest)                                                         
if ok {
    if v, ok := req.(*account.PostAccountRequest); ok { // note ":"
      panic(ok)
  }
}
```

... but does not make sense because `v` can only be one of the struct types.

Perhaps you are looking for something like this:

```
var name, token string
switch v := v.(type) {
case *account.CreateAccountRequest:
 // v is a *account.CreateAccountRequest in this branch of the switch
 name = v.Name
 token = v.Token
case *account.PostAccountRequest:
 // v is a *account.PostAccountRequest in this branch of the switch
 name = v.Name
 token = v.Token
default:
 // panic?
}
```

Comment: And the reason I do it is because I need  a global variable `v`, then I can do this like `v.name v.token`@Mellow Marmot

Comment: account.CreateAccountRequest  {name string, token string, passwd string } and account.PostAccountRequest {name string, token string}, They have two same field

Comment: Although two of fields are identical, not all fields are identical. They are different types.